# The best place for Help in mobile app?

Tags: mobile, architecture, settings

I'm a Ui/Ux designer, and I've been asked to give some advice on the architecture of an iPhone app, the said app implies a section called 'Help and guides' for the users to know how to properly enter their data in the app. While analyzing the app, I was going to recommand that it may be interesting to put that part in the settings, and I was challenged about the reason I would do that. All I could come up with was that it was kind of a habit to put it there. But indeed, why would we put the help in the settings?

While doing some research, it appears that the help and the FAQs are often placed in the settings of the apps, and I was wondering why. Even though it seems obvisous to me that this has evolve into a known pattern to the user, I was wondering if there was a proper justification for this practice. Any ideas or clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research into this as I am currently designing Android and IOS Apps. The reason to group both these items under the one menu is to keep the screen as clutter less as possible. Due to the screen size of a mobile phone, the need for space is high so removing the buttons by grouping them under the one menu helps greatly.

I would suggest possibly making a Menu button with the options to access help & settings as subheadings personally.

Comment: The screen size was a part of my justification, but for me, in some way, it doesn't make sens to give access to the help through the settings, even if it has become a pattern. Plus in some case the help and guides are required to be read by the user so they properly use the app. I'm not a fan of the forced tutorial on first use, but that will probably be an option here, in addition of creating a general menu in which we'll find the settings and the help among other things.

Thank you for your answer Michael!